# Read and write a DB file stored in aws s3 (Heroku + Django)

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, amazon-s3, heroku-postgres

I´m stuck with an easy requirement, I appreciate any ideas!

First the enviroment: Django app deployed on Heroku with a Postgres DB and serving the static files from AWS S3.

I have a model with a FileField, and when I upload a file it is stored in a AWS S3 bucket.

I just need to read the file, write some text and save it again, it should be easy, right?

I managed to do it in dev in my laptop, but when I deploy the app to heroku I get a lot of errors like a file path error (I guess it tries to look for the aws bucket path in the heroku server), write permmissions and some others...

Am I doing something wrong? How can I achieve this?
Thx in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking wrong...

The solutions is to read and write directly in the defined storage:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
with default_storage.open(model.field.name, "w+") as f:
    f.write("hello")
```

Hope this can be useful to anyone